# How can I use JQuery countdown to start counting the remaining time after the "change" event from a bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [JQuery countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and I'm having problems making it work with events.

Here's the span:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label>Tempo Restante</label>
    <span class="remaining-time"></span>
</div>
```

Here's the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d;
    var t;
    var expirationTime;

    $("#PedidoDateFimData").change(function() {
        var d = $("#PedidoDateFimData").val();
        var t = $("#PedidoDateFimHour").val();
        var parsedTime = t.split(':');
        expirationTime = parseSlashDate(d);
        expirationTime.setHours(parsedTime[0]);
        expirationTime.setMinutes(parsedTime[1]);
    });

    $("#PedidoDateFimHour").change( function() {
        d = $("#PedidoDateFimData").val();
        t = $("#PedidoDateFimHour").val();
        var parsedTime = t.split(':');
        expirationTime = parseSlashDate(d);
        expirationTime.setHours(parsedTime[0]);
        expirationTime.setMinutes(parsedTime[1]);
    });

    $(".remaining-time").countdown({until: expirationTime, format: "dHMS", compact: true}); 
}
```

And here's the parseSlashDate function:

```
function parseSlashDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('/');
  // new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]); 
}
```

"PedidoDateFimData" is a bootstrap datepicker in the following brazilian format:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    keyboardNavigation: true,
    // startDate: new Date()
});
```

"PedidoDateFimHour" is a normal time field ("23:32", for example).

I keep getting "invalid date" if I use setInterval, and even when I don't get, the countdown does not work. How can I use JQuery countdown to start counting the remaining time after the "change" event from a bootstrap Datepicker?

Here's the missing data:

```
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Vencimento (Prazo)</label>
                <input name="data[Pedido][date_fim_data]" placeholder="* Ex: 31/06/2013" type="text" id="PedidoDateFimData" class="datepicker ttip" title="Informe a Data e hora finais do prazo para a entrega do seu Pedido" required="required">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>Horário</label>
                <input name="data[Pedido][date_fim_hour]" placeholder="* hh:mm" type="text" id="PedidoDateFimHour" class="hora" required="required">
              </div>
```

Comment: You're missing the #PedidoDateFimData and #PedidoDateFimHour html tags here. How are they related? How are you putting in the day / hours ?

Comment: I've edited the question and added the missing data.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have your whole code at hand.

1) both the $('.').change methods had the same code. I just put them together as update().

2) I added a undefined check on the time field.

3) You don't have to parse the date yourself. JQ $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate') will do that for you.

```
function update() {

  var expirationTime = $("#PedidoDateFimData").datepicker("getDate"),
    t = $("#PedidoDateFimHour").val(),
    parsedTime = t.split(':');

  if (parsedTime.length == 2) {
    expirationTime.setHours(parsedTime[0]);
    expirationTime.setMinutes(parsedTime[1]);
  }

  $('.remaining-time').countdown({until: expirationTime, format: 'dHM'})

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#PedidoDateFimData").change(update);
  $("#PedidoDateFimHour").change(update);
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  todayBtn: "linked",
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  keyboardNavigation: true,
  // startDate: new Date()
});
```